# How can I prevent a CodenameOne GUI Element from scrolling (tickering?) when it changes to Bold?

Tags: java, codenameone

I am building my first CodenameOne app using the GUI Builder.   I've defined a style for my buttons where the "unselected" state is regular text and the "selected" or focus state has Bold text.

The problem I'm seeing is that once a button gains focus, the bold text is slightly wider than the original text and it starts scrolling (I think the effect is referred to as "tickering"):

[Unselected Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poBEG.png)

[Selected Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ4FU.png)

I see this in the simulator and on my Samsung SG6 testing.  Is this a bug or is there something I can do to pre-size it for the bold text first so it doesn't start scrolling when it gets focus?  I don't want to make the button larger than it needs to be (ie: fit it to a container)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 things,

- first reduce the left and right padding of the selected button UIID and then call this in your code

  ```
  mybutton.setEndsWith3Points(false);
  mybutton.setTickerEnabled(false);
  ```

As an extra, place the button in a container with the right layout.

Note that since the text is now Bold, it's normal for the button to gain extra width. So I will suggest you make a room for that.

**Edit:**

I noticed that the button was tickering when you took the snapshot so ignore the first point about padding.